# how to start each line with the same line spacing?

Tags: lyx

[image]

I need to set it so that wfef, fewefwe and wfe is just below fwefwewefwfe, but can't get that to work.... I don't want them to be so far in front, how can I make it work?

Comment: what you ask for is the default layout, so you need to not do whatever you are doing in code you have not shown,

Comment: You probably have blank lines between the input text lines.  That indicates a paragraph break, so the output lines are indented.  This is one of the very few situations in which indicating a line break with `\\ ` is appropriate.  {I'm guessing.  This is why we ask for a compilable code example that shows exactly what you're doing.)

Comment: If you go to Document > Settings > Text Layout and put the bullet point on "Indentation" and then change "Default" to "Custom" and then put 0 in the box and then press OK, does that do what you want?

Comment: Hi, provide small example of Your work please starting with  ```\documentclass```

Comment: You have here one section title and 4 paragraphs. The first paragraph is not indented because is under the title, so it is obvious were it start. The others are indented to point were they start. If you type longer paragraphs (of more of one line)  you will see why you are obtaining this apparent misalignment.  If you want mark  paragraphs with some vertical spaces instead of  indentation, follow the comment of  scottkosty, but instead of check "indentation, choose "Vertical Space".  If you are trying to do some that is not just normal paragraphs of text,  this is not the way.